# How do I calculate eigenvectors with KDB?

Tags: kdb

I feel like I've gotten 'stuck' here; I can't seem to find anything in the docs to help.

I'm trying to calculate the eigenvectors of a square matrix. Currently I have my matrix defined as a function `f[x;y]`.

Is there an equivalent of LAPACK's QR algorithm in KDB? (or alternatively, can I connect to LAPACK from KDB?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the qml library developed by Andrey Zholos located here: https://github.com/zholos/qml. It is built ontop of libraries such as LAPACK.

The function for calculating the eigenvectors is `mev` and the input parameter is the matrix